# Form doesn`t check the validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to check if there is an error but now it doensn't check anaything. the form submits even when the fields are empty. Dont know where the fault is. Can somebody help all the fields in the form are correct I think something goes wrong in the `if(error == 0)`:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var errormsg = ['Please enter name.', 'Please enter minimum 3 character.', 'Value not more than 100 characters.', 'Please enter email.', 'Please enter valid email.', 'Email and confirm email does not match.', 'Please enter password', 'Please enter role.', 'Email already exists'];

    $("input[type='submit']").on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $(".validationError").remove();


        var span_error_start = '<span class="form_error">';
        var span_error_end = "</span>";

        var name           = $.trim($("input[name='name']").val());
        var problem        = $.trim($("input[name='problem']").val());
        var description    = $.trim($("input[name='description']").val());

        var error = 0;



        if(name == ""){
            $("input[name='name']").after("<div class='nameInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[0]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;

        }
        else if(name.length < 3){
            $("input[name='name']").after("<div class='nameInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[1]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }
        else if(name.length > 100){
            $("input[name='name']").after("<div class='nameInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[2]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }




        if(problem == ""){
            $("input[name='problem']").after("<div class='problemInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[3]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }
        else if(problem.length < 3){
            $("input[name='problem']").after("<div class='problemInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[1]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }
        else if(problem.length > 100){
            $("input[name='problem']").after("<div class='problemInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[2]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }



        if(description == ""){
            $("input[name='description']").after("<div class='descriptionInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[6]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }
        else if(description.length < 3){
            $("input[name='description']").after("<div class='descriptionInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[1]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }
        else if(description.length > 100){
            $("input[name='description']").after("<div class='descriptionInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[2]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
            error = 1;
        }




        if(error == 0){

            $(".myForm").submit();

        }
}

        else{
            return false;
        }

    });




</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the full code? Make a snippet by pressing Ctrl + M?

Comment: i will update it 1 moment

Comment: Please add your input values that you expect to throw an error.

Comment: is this enough mario?

Comment: @user3356007 Kindly add your HTML too, please? The whole file would be awesome.

Comment: @user3356007 I am definitely gonna solve this in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Error in your code. Extra braces, so else doesn't work. Syntax error:

```
  if(error == 0){
    $(".myForm").submit();
  }
} // Extra braces, so else doesn't work. Syntax error. So remove it.

  else {
    return false;
  }
```

**Updated Correct Code:**

```
if(error == 0){
  $(".myForm").submit();
}

else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @user3356007 I asked you to remove that line. What did you understand? Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem :

```
    if(error == 0){

        $(".myForm").submit();

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

    });
```

Comment: Yes, like I answered something totally different!